# showing 1 data from Sqlflite flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, sqlite, dart

So i want to make a delete button, so the user could delete those data according to the data they choose to see.

Each time the data on the sqflite were added the delete button increase shown here on the picture

Heres the picture when theres only 1 data
[image]

and here's the picture when they got more than 1 data
[image]

Here's My code on how the delete work and the Code of how they were build

```
FutureBuilder(
                      future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getCards(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Cards>> snapshot) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          width: 40.w,
                          child: Column(
                            children: snapshot.data!.map((cards) {
                              return SizedBox(
                                width: 40.w,
                                child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Color(0xffBE4E49),
                                  textColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    // null;
                                    setState(() {
                                      DatabaseHelper.instance.remove(cards.id!);
                                    });
                                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => new HomeScreen()),
                                          (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: Text(
                                    'DELETE',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 13.sp,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }),
```